# iOS Size Classes, Uninstalled Views and Outlets

Tags: ios, class, size

I have an outlet for a UILabel. The label is "installed" for Any Width and Any Height, but "uninstalled" for Compact Width and Any Height.

When I run this project with the iPhone 5 simulator (Compact Width, Any Height), I can still see a valid outlet.  Why is this?  Shouldn't it be nil or something?  I was also thinking it is valid but just hidden (I can't see the outlet, but isHidden is false).  What happens to it?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple's Size Classes Design Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH11-SW1)

> A runtime object for an uninstalled view is still created. However,
>   the view and any related constraints are not added to the view
>   hierarchy and the view has a superview property of nil. This is
>   different from being hidden. A hidden view is in the view hierarchy
>   along as are any related constraints.

If you look at the `superView` property of your uninstalled `UILabel` you will see that it is `nil`.

If the outlet itself was nil you could have issues if you tried to access it;  your code would have to explicitly check the active size class and adapt its behaviour.  By still creating the object but not adding it to the view hierarchy your code can still operate on the label, its just that those operations won't have any visible effect.